# How to use standard result type from Alamofile with no-type Success?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, alamofire

I'm trying to reuse Alamofire's Result type for own API callbacks.
Here is a shortened version of result type I'm using:

```
public enum Result<Value> {
    case Success(Value) 
    case Failure(NSData?, ErrorType)
}
```

So for my API calls I'm using it in completion blocks:

```
func getUserContent(userId: String, completion: (result: Result<User>) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(UserRouter.GetUser(userId))
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { (request, response, result) -> Void in
                switch result {
                case .Failure(_, let error):
                    completion(result: .Failure(nil, error))
                case .Success(let value):
                    if let responseDict = value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                        do {
                            // synchronous call which parses response and 
                            // creates User struct instance or throws exception
                            let user = try self.processUserResponse(responseDict)
                            completion(result: .Success(user))
                        } catch(let error) {
                            completion(result: .Failure(nil, error))
                        }
                    } else {
                        completion(result: .Failure(nil, MyAPIError.WrongResponseFormat))
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

I think its perfectly fits here but there is one issue. I have some calls with completion blocks which supposed to return either .Success with *no value* or .Failure. 
E.g. `deleteUser` method should look something like:

```
func deleteUser(userId: String, completion: (result: Result<nil>) -> Void) {
 // ... do some stuff here 
}
```

so when I call it later I can do:

```
deleteUser(userId) { (result) -> Void in
            switch result {
            case .Success:
                print("success")
            case .Failure(nil, let error):
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
```

But I can't create "empty" `.Success`. `Result<nil>` of course gives me a compile error. But I don't have any type to pass to some of `.Success` cases. Does anyone has a better solution that defining another Result Type with no type on `.Success`?

Answer (score 3):

@ogreswamp is right! You can omit the type requirement with `Void`. Type `Void` is simply an empty tuple, in effect a tuple with zero elements, which can be written as (). Here is an example:

```
enum Result<T, E: ErrorType> {
    case Success(T)
    case Failure(E)

    init(value: T) {
        self = .Success(value)
    }

    init(error: E) {
        self = .Failure(error)
    }
}
```

Use this like

```
enum AuthenticationError: ErrorType {
    case MissingEmail
    case InvalidPassword
}

func signUp(email email: String, password: String) -> Result<Void, AuthenticationError>
```

You can return the result like

```
// Success
return Result(value: ())

// Failure
return Result(error: .InvalidPassword)
```

And finally, check the result

```
switch result {
case .Success(_):
    print("Request SignUp was sent")
case .Failure(let error):
    switch error {
    case .InvalidEmail:
        print("Invalid email")
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to define your own `Result` type. Also note that Alamofire 3.0 uses a much different `Result` type that may better suit your needs.

Comment: I actually found that `func deleteUser(userId: String, completion: (result: Result<Void>) -> Void)` will suit this need